# Sieve of Eratosthenes python

Tags: python, primes

I have to use the below to create a program

```
create an empty list P to hold primes     
create a sieve list S of length n + 1. Set every element in S to True    
ITERATE over p from 2 to n  
    IF the element at p in S is True   
        add the element at p in S to P   
        generate multiples m of p up to n in increments of p   
             set the elements at all m in S to False   
return P
```

So far i have produced the following code but i get an empty list when P is returned.
any ideas as to what is wrong?

```
def prime(n):
  P = []
  s = [n+1]
  s == True
  for p in range(2, n):
      if p in s == True:
          p.append(P)
          for m in range(p*p, n+1, p):
              m == False
  return P
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to say `if p in s == True:`, you can just say `if p in s:`.

Comment: `m == False` is an expression. Maybe you meant `m = False`?

Comment: You're also appending `P` (your list) to `p` (your iterator variable).  I'm assuming you wanted `P.append(p)`.  In general I'd recommend using more descriptive names so you avoid this issue.

Comment: So i have made the suggested amendments but still getting an empty list for P when returned??

Answer (score 2):

You didn't create `s` to be a list of `n+1` `True`s; you created a list with *one* element, `n+1`, and then ask if it is `True` (and ignore the answer).  Try this instead:

```
s = [True for x in xrange(n+1)]
```

You also never *do* anything to `s`, but one thing at a time.